# How to achieve the best UX with Flutter form AutovalidateMode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve the best UX on Flutter using `AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction`.

**Option 1**

When I set the validation on the form key, when a user tries to type one one texField the whole form goes red with errors.

```
 child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
```

**Option 2**

When I set  `AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` on each text field I end up getting the error on each textfield when the user tries to type and it disappears when they complete the input.

```
 RoundedPasswordResetField(
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Please Re-enter Password';
                                      }
                                      if (password != confirmpassword) {
                                        return "Password does not match";
                                      }
                                      //
                                      return null;
                                    },
                                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                    hintText: "Please Re-enter Password",
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      confirmpassword = value;
                                    },
                                  ),
```

**Option 3**

When I set it to `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,`, when the user tries to submit the fields when they are empty, the errors appear, but when they key in the specific correct details the errors don't clear out

```
 RoundedPasswordResetField(
                                        validator: (value) {
                                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                                            return 'Please Re-enter Password';
                                          }
                                          if (password != confirmpassword) {
                                            return "Password does not match";
                                          }
                                          //
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                                        hintText: "Please Re-enter Password",
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          confirmpassword = value;
                                        },
                                      ),
```

How can I use `setState`, so that when the user starts typing the errors wont be shown immediately, and shown when they complete inputting  wrong details - and achieve the best UX?

Comment: I think you should use option 2 and pass a unique key to RoundedPasswordResetField.

Comment: Hi @TipuSultan, thank you for your response, but  this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Hey @arriff I have same question like you , I want to show errors only that time when user come into that textfield.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something I implemented in one of my Android projects two years ago. Although, it was Kotlin, still I opened my Github and looked for it.

First, let's understand your question: The question says that `Autovalidate` mode shouldn't be there or should be left to default (`AutovalidateMode.disabled`) to not do the validation whenever user starts typing which is obviously a bad UX. But, it should work only after the user stops with enough delay to consider it as completion of typing which means whenever there is a brief stoppage in the input data stream.

Now, for this, `PublishProcessor.debounce()` of RxJava is a good option in Kotlin, which can be used in dart using packages like [`rxdart`](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart). What it does is it prevents continuous execution of a function and only executes the function after a certain delay, if the function is triggered again, it resets the delay. So, the funtion executes only once and that too, only after a certain delay imitating the effect of user stopped typing.

Use [this - Just Debounce It](https://pub.dev/packages/just_debounce_it) package, it's not as over-kill as RxDart but still, there are [many alternatives](https://pub.dev/packages?q=debounce).

Implement it as

```
void function validateForm() {
  Debounce.seconds(2, //2 means run this function only after 2 second delay.
    () => formKey.currentState.validate()) //This is a function passed as a Callback which is executed only when it crosses the delay.
}
```

And call this function from `onChanged` as:

```
onChanged: (val) => validateForm()
```

That's it. Now, your form will only be validated if the user stops typing. This is the go-to way, not just good UX but good logic. There are hacks to make this work with `booleans` and `postDelayed` but that's bad code.